# Get users list from the table using SQLalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model like this.

```
class Message(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    from_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    to_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    from_user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[from_id], uselist=False)
    to_user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[to_id],
                          uselist=False)
    date = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP(), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    room_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("room.id"), nullable=False)
```

What I want to achieve is, for given a `user_id`, I want to get the list of user to whom the user has messaged or from which users user has received messages from.

For ex:

consider there are 3 users with ids 1,2,3

**Messages sent**

```
1 -> 2

2 -> 1

1 -> 3

3 -> 2
```

Now for user id 1, I want to get the users list with id 2 and 3. and for user 2 ,i would 1 and 3.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is as below:

```
def get_users(user_id):
    messages = cls.query.filter(or_(cls.from_id == user_id, cls.to_id == user_id)).subquery()

    users = User.query.join(messages, or_(messages.c.to_id == User.id,
                           messages.c.from_id == User.id)).filter(User.id != user_id)

    return users
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you're after is to take the union of users that meet your criteria.

```
user_id = 1

messaged_to = User.query.\
    join(Message, Message.to_id == User.id).\
    filter(Message.from_id == user_id)

messages_from = User.query.\
    join(Message, Message.from_id == User.id).\
    filter(Message.to_id == user_id)

query = messaged_to.union(messages_from)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. :)